# How could we experience the power of object oriented programming in procedural language?

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstraction, procedural-programming

As we know that the Object oriented programming language has lots of benefit.But in same implementation procedural language like C do not have any alternative like realtime applications. So can we combine the power of two to create a great application?
Can we experience the major pillars of OOPS in procedural language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly all general-purpose languages are Turing equivalent.  This means -- among other thing -- that anything you can dream up in one language, you can implement in another.  So yes, it's *possible*, though it isn't enforced by the compiler as strictly as an OOP zealot might like.

Consider C's `FILE` type (used by `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, etc).  It's not specified what exactly is in there, and you don't need to know or care (read: encapsulation); all you have to know is, you can `fopen` you a file, `fread`/`fwrite` it, and when you're done, you `fclose`.  Thing is, that "file" can be anywhere -- at the root of the FS, in your homedir that's on a whole other drive...in most OSes, it can even be a pipe or a network socket (read: polymorphism).

Basically, the funnest parts of OOP.  And we didn't say "class" even once.  :)